# Consolidating Columns in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, analysis

I have a huge dataset and I want to sum the rows of multiple columns so I can combine them into a single summed column. I am working in `R`. I have successfully summed the rows up, but am not sure how to add them as a new column to the dataframe. If I delete the original columns, I am worried my sum code won't work anymore, however the goal is to delete the original columns and create one new one. How can I do this?

I used the below code to sum the columns, now I need to figure out how to save them as one column and add it to the dataframe, while deleting the original columns:

```
rowSums(
acs_df[ , c("Total.Population..Under.5.Years", "Total.Population..5.to.9.Years", "Total.Population..10.to.14.Years", "Total.Population..15.to.17.Years")]
)
```

I want one single column called `Total.Population..0.to.17.Years` which is the sum of the above columns. My issue is that it is a HUGE dataset with 100 variables and I can't `pivot_longer` to reshape and manipulate.

Any advice on how to proceed or suggestion on an alternative approach appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a reproducible example so that we could help.

Comment: `acs_df$Total.Population..0.to.17.Year <- rowSums( . . . .)` then `acs_df <- acs_df[,ncol(acs_df)]`

Comment: There are a few things to query - mainly, you say "it is a HUGE dataset with 100 variables and I can't pivot_longer to reshape and manipulate" but why not? That said, the most obvious thing would be to assign your existing code to a new column:  `acs_df$\`Total.Population..0.to.17.Years\` <- (rowSums(acs_df[, c("Total.Population..Under.5.Years", "Total.Population..5.to.9.Years", "Total.Population..10.to.14.Years", "Total.Population..15.to.17.Years")]))`

Comment: Thank you all! This is helpful. I am just not sure how to pivot_longer only a portion of the dataset and thought I would have to add every single variable name in the code to do that. I am very much an R newbie. Thanks for the help! This does successfully add my new column "Total.Population..15.to.17.Years" but does not get rid of the four columns I used to sum for that column. Is there any way to delete those columns after adding the new column, or would that mess up the equation?

Comment: you can set a column to NULL to remove it in base R. `acs_df["Total.Population..Under.5.Years"] <- NULL`  for example